# Change object property depending on integer value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object, Player, which has different properties for different rounds for example round_1, round_2, .. , round_7. I would like to give them values depending on the integer, round value.

What i thought would work would be with a function:

```
//voor = round in Estonian
function valiVoor(player, r){
if (r == 1){
    return player.voor_1;
}
else if (r == 2){
    return player.voor_2;
}
else if (r == 3){
    return player.voor_3;
}
else if (r == 4){
    return player.voor_4;
}
else if (r == 5){
    return player.voor_5;
}
else if (r == 6){
    return player.voor_6;
}
else if (r == 7){
    return player.voor_7;
}
}
```

Although calling out function:

```
valiVoor(player_one,1) = "asd";
```

Will not change the property player_one.voor_1 = "asd". Should i work with arrays or is there any other option to resolve the issue?

Comment: So what's your issue?

Comment: Sorry, had connectivity problems and some text got lost, edited

Comment: where's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function valiVoor(player, r){
    return player['voor_'+r];
}
```

And a setter:

```
function setValiVoor(player, r, value){
    player['voor_'+r] = value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this setter helped alot

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation):

```
player['voor_' + r] = 'asd'; //Equivalent to player.voor_# where # is the number r
```

If you want to check if the property exists before assigning (otherwise if `r` goes crazy it takes your `player` object in its madness):

```
if(player.hasOwnProperty('voor_' + r)) {
  //Do stuff
}
```

See this [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) for `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also access Object properties with the squared brackets just like Arrays.

```
function getValiVoor(player, r){
    return player['voor_' + r];
}
```

If you want to assign a value, you could pass the value to the function:

```
function setValiVoor(player, r, val){
    player['voor_' + r] = val;
}
```